# How to get values of cursor object by using Python

Tags: python, mongodb, find, pymongo, database-cursor

I have data in mondoDB;

```
db.np_tpy_gla.find({},{"_id":0, "c": 1})
```

Result:

```
{ "c" : NumberLong(18) }
{ "c" : NumberLong(40) }
{ "c" : NumberLong(42) }
{ "c" : NumberLong(54) }
...
```

I am trying to get these values by using Python (pymongo).
Here is my code:

```
counterNumber = cursor.count()
gettingTotalSize = cursor.find({"c": True})

print counterNumber 
print gettingTotalSize
```

and here is result:

```
115
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x13c7890>
```

I'm tring to get "gettingTotalSize" values one by one.

How can i get these values? i also tried for loop.

Thanks.

EDIT :

I changed my codes like:

```
gettingTotalSize = cursor.find({}, {"_id": 0, "c": 1})
```

Vignesh Kalai'codes:

```
for x in gettingTotalSize :
    print x
```

Here is the new result :

```
{u'c': 18L}
{u'c': 40L}
{u'c': 42L}
{u'c': 54L}
...
```

Now I need only the value (18,40,42,54...)

Any ideas? :)

Comment: did you try looping over `gettingTotalSize ` since it returns a cursor you can loop over it

Comment: like? i tried something and didnt work

Comment: Could you post what you have tried and what you got

Comment: i tried lots of :) one of them; for x in range(0, gettingTotalSize ):
  print gettingTotalSize [x]  AND result: EXPECTION: no such item for Cursor instance

Comment: How about `for row in gettingTotalSize :print row `

Comment: Ok it worked and i did some changes but now i have a new problem :) i edited my question for my new problem :)

Comment: How about `x.values()` if you have only one `key:value` pair or `x["c"]`

Comment: It is done :) x["c"] works well :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help I will paste the answer can you accept it

Comment: of course, thanks again

Comment: Always Happy to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To iterate over a `cursor` you could loop over the cursor and to get element out of a dictionary you could pass it's key to get value

**Code:**

```
for x in gettingTotalSize :
    print x["c"]
```